# Radgrid Excel Export In Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I tried to export the data to excel using radgrid option, it's working fine on single export. but I tried to export in for each loop, last file data's only exported. Is possible to export in loop?

```
protected void btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string selectedimportfilesid = "";
            IList<RadListBoxItem> collection = ListBoxFileNames.CheckedItems;
            string selectedfilename = "";
            DataTable dtselect = new DataTable();
            foreach (RadListBoxItem item in collection)
            {
                Label filename = (Label)item.FindControl("lblfilename");
                Label Importfileid = (Label)item.FindControl("lblimportfileid");
                selectedfilename = filename.Text;
                selectedimportfilesid = Importfileid.Text;
                dtselect = selectedexportfilelist(selectedimportfilesid);
                testgrid.DataSource = dtselect; 
                testgrid.DataBind();
                testgrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
                testgrid.ExportSettings.FileName = selectedfilename 
                testgrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
                testgrid.ExportSettings.Excel.FileExtension = "xls";
                testgrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
            }
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the file (selectedfilename) in each iteration, so only the last iteration's contents are going to "survive". Add a counter or something like that to selectedfilename to make a unique file name for each iteration.

Comment: Each selected file name have a unique , so file name not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. The ExportToExcel() method is designed to send the exported content to the end user, so it changes the Response object (writes the file there and adds the appropriate headers). So, doing it several times over will just change the file in the response stream with the last one.

Probably, you could:

1. generate your files with your data yourself, and store them (e.g., in a temp folder: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/export-infrastructure.html
2. zip them: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ziplibrary-overview.html
3. send them to the client
4. delete the temp files

but I have not tested this, nor have I used it, so I cannot say if it is feasible for your case.

Comment: It is good to mark the useful answer as answer and even post what you did to solve the original problem so you help others